# Baked edge mask image behaving differently to edge mask node group

Tags: image, masking

I created an edge mask node group in cycles - baked an image texture from that, when I apply the texture to an object, it behaves differently than the node group:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: Added images of the shader editor and uploaded the blend file:

https://pasteall.org/blend/8ac7e2ad6370469d87a4c2a1f6cf171b

Comment: hello, it's hard to guess why, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your object's uv map

Comment: Apologies, added some more information and included the blend file.